# This function is giving my program a core dump and I can't figure out why

Tags: c, pointers, io, fopen, singly-linked-list

My other functions work fine but once I call this readfile funtions, I have an exit code/core dump.  Temp is pointer pointing to a double pointer (the linked list itself).  I have a feeling the error is somewhere in the first 6 lines because I am positive everything else is correct.

I have tried to change around my strategy in of the temp->next and how I move the pointer throughout the list but nothing seems to work

```
while ( !feof(fp) && return_val == 0 ){
            if ( temp != NULL ){
                temp = malloc(sizeof(struct record));
                temp->next = next;
                next->next = NULL;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            fscanf(fp, "%*s %*s %d",&temp->accountno);
            track = 0;
            while ( track == 0 ){
                ch = fgetc(fp);
                if ( ch == '<'){
                    ch = fgetc(fp);
                    while ( ch != '>' ){
                        temp->name[ni] = ch;
                        ch = fgetc(fp);
                        ni++;
                    }
                    temp->name[ni] = '\0';
                } else if ( ch == '['){
                        ch = fgetc(fp);
                        while ( ch != ']' ){
                            temp->address[ai] = ch;
                            ch = fgetc(fp);
                            ai++;
                        }
                        temp->address[ai] = '\0';
                        track = 1;
                }
            }
            ni = 0;
            ai = 0;
        }
```

I expect the program to simply read the file, the function takes in a double pointer and a string array(name of the file) and it is supposed to read from the file, the account number, name, and address and store it in the linked list.

Comment: Not an answer, but do read [Why is `while(!feof(file))` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I tend to agree that the problem is likely to be in the first few lines, because I'm having trouble figuring out what they're supposed to do, or why you want to do that only in the event that `temp` is initially **non**-null.  It sort of looks like you're trying to prepend a new node to the head of the list, but it also sort of looks like you're trying to append one to the tail of the list.  Note in particular that if `temp` is initially null then you will get a null-pointer dereference when the `fscanf` arguments are evaluated.

Comment: If temp==NULL, you're doing strange things

Comment: Did you mean if ( temp == NULL ) ? That would seem more reasonable than what you have now.

Comment: when asking a question about a run-time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `temp = malloc(sizeof(struct record));`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" );`  to output both you error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: what is the `struct` definition of the fields in each entry in the linked list?

Comment: what is contained in the variable: `next`?

Comment: regarding: `while ( ch != '>' ){
                        temp->name[ni] = ch;
                        ch = fgetc(fp);
                        ni++;
                    }
                    temp->name[ni] = '\0';`  What if there is not enough room in the `name[]` array?

Comment: where is `return_val` set?

Comment: regarding: `read the file, the function takes in a double pointer and a string array(name of the file) and it is supposed to read from the file, the account number, name, and address and store it in the linked list.`   What does a typical line in the file look like?

Comment: regarding: `fscanf(fp, "%*s %*s %d",&temp->accountno)`  1)  What if those first two strings contain spaces?  2) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  in the current scenario, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred